# Changing column numbering system in Calc (spreadsheet), Not the formatting

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice

I am trying to convert a numbering system in an old dbase file. I have manage to open it in calc and, before I use it as a table in a new database created with base, there is a field (column) I would like to modify.

The actual format is ex : 100-1234-56 I would like to:

add a 1 in front of it, keep the first 3 numbers, remove the dash, keep the next four numbers and remove the dash with the last 2 numbers like this:

100-1234-56 would be 11001234

What are my options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your first number is in cell A1, enter the following formula into cell B1:

=CONCATENATE("1";MID(A1;1;3);MID(A1;5;4))

The "MID" function extracts a text sub-string from cell A1.  For example, the first instance starts at 1 and extracts 3 characters giving the "100" string.  Concatenate adds the substrings together so that your new value starts off as 1 + 100, and so on.

Comment: That did it... awesome, now if I want to get rid of Column A, I will lose the data has column B is the formula... How do I get the result to be the value of the cell itself, I tried to do a copy/special paste with only text but it adds a 'before the number, it is not visible in the cell itself but it is in the input line. Will that reflect in my table ?

Comment: Now that you have B1, the quick way is to make cell C1 =VALUE(B1) to convert the text string to a number.  Now, copy cell C1 and Paste-Special into cell D1 with Selection=Numbers in order to retain the numeric value.  Of course, since you wanted the final product to be a number, you could have included the Value function in the initial transformation by making cell B1 =VALUE(CONCATENATE("1";MID(A1;1;3);MID(A1;5;4)))